# mxmlc (flex compiler) ignores "define" from xml configs

Tags: actionscript-3, conditional-compilation, mxmlc

From Adobe's [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html):

> To set the value of these constants in the flex-config.xml file, rather than on the command line, you write this as the following example shows:

```
<compiler> 
    <define append="true"> 
        <name>CONFIG::debugging</name> 
        <value>true</value> 
    </define> 
    <define append="true"> 
        <name>CONFIG::release</name> 
        <value>false</value> 
    </define> 
</compiler>
```

The problem is that compiler doesn't actually take them into account and giving me compilation errors like "Error: Access of undefined property debugging." since I have that in my ActionScript code.

If I define them via arguments ("-define+=CONFIG::debugging,true") everything is OK.

I thought maybe my config is not used at all, so I malformed it — mxmlc points that out. So config is actually loaded into compiler.

Any hints? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was the XML problem — as I actually had strings, not booleans, in config — you should not forget to write the proper XML (weird that compiler didn't say me back anything).

```
<value>&quot;MyStringValue&quot;</value>
```

Or easier:

```
<value>'MyStringValue'</value>
```

And double-quoting ('"MyStringValue"') is when you're using arguments.

Comment: Yes, I know about quoting issue for strings (had the same in my experience) but your example is with boolean values so I didn't consider it as a potential cause )

Comment: And a note to myself: post the actual stuff, do not over-simplify =)

Answer (score 2):

I use the same approach for passing DEFINE params via loading custom-config and all works fine. I don't see error in the part of config you provided.

Here is [my variant](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ba4qcw3y2ntd59v/config-local.xml?dl=0) of config and mxmlc params:

```
-load-config tools/config-local.xml -dump-config=local-dumped-config.xml.
```

Also check the dump config to be sure defines were included.

Comment: In dumped config there are no defines, but these lines (exactly, copied from there):

<load-config>${flexlib}/${configname}-config.xml</load-config>
   <load-config>/Users/fljot/Development/Projects/BirdsWheel/build/metsaylem-config.xml</load-config>

Comment: I can only advice you to test on demo project, all should works. There should be a simple solution for your issue, but it pretty hard to find it remotely.

Comment: Could you post respective part of your dumped config please?

Comment: It's 100% the same (in case I use -load-config+= rather than -load-config):
   <load-config>${flexlib}/${configname}-config.xml</load-config>
   <load-config>tools/config-local.xml</load-config>
but with defines.

Comment: Posted my answer, but still thank you for confirming the general idea. Upvoted.